# Usage of "instead of"

Tags: word-usage

My question is about using the adverb "instead of". Am I right in understanding that the said adverb is usually followed by things that did not happen in the past in the story of a speaker?

You picked up **someone else's keys**. But you should have taken yours. So you could not get to the apartment because  **someone else's keys** didn't fit the lock.

So we cannot say that

> You should have taken your keys instead of [..].

It is not correct usage, isn’t it?

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason to assume *instead of* to have an "irrealis" aspect. It's simply "A, not B". If you take a look at the etymology of [instead](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/instead), you'll see that it simply means "in the place of" or "substituting" (which again has the common latin root *situ* = place in it).

Your sentence is absolutely fine:

> You should have taken your keys **instead of** someone else's.

Works the other way round, too (but is much more complicated):

> You shouldn't have taken someone else's keys **instead of** yours.

Comment: **You picked up someone else's keys instead of yours**. I thought that version would be correct.  It seemed to me that speakers of English usually mentioned unrealized things after _instead of_. :) Now I see that the sentence in question is fine. Thanks.

Comment: @AmD: Your bold text is correct, too. *instead of* is quite simple to use if you keep the "in place of"/"substitute" - root in mind. And of course it's often figuratively used, not with "real" places.

Comment: And "unrealized" comes with choosing A *instead of* B - so B becomes an option that didn't happen. But not neccessarily so, think sports: "In the second half, instead of Mark, John led the offense, confusing the opponent's defense." (-> with Mark being the offense in the 1st half)

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of** is a preposition. This preposition combined with a noun is a preposition phrase. This preposition phrase can be an adverb.

**Instead of** is not a conjunction, which connect 2 similar entities.